# on input event not working on when using button value

Tags: jquery

I have here an `input` that getting it's value from buttons. `on input` event not working when I want to get the value of the `input`. Please see code below for reference.

```js
var cashin_amount = 0;
$(".button-amount").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var amount = $(this).text();
    amount = amount.replace(",", "");
    $("#txtAmount").val(amount);
    cashin_amount = amount;
});

$("#txtAmount").on("input", function () {
    var val = this.val();
    alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtAmount" disabled />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>1,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>2,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>3,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>5,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>10,000</button>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: when i change the value of input using the button, the on input event not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"input"` event happens when the user directly types into a form control. The data entered in `<input>` was done indirectly through the `"click"` event triggered from the `<button>`. Just tie into the `"click"` event for event handling, the results are the same (see demo).

```js
var cashin_amount = 0;
$(".button-amount").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var amount = $(this).text();
    amount = amount.replace(",", "");
    $("#txtAmount").val(amount);
    cashin_amount = amount;
    alert(amount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtAmount" disabled />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>1,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>2,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>3,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>5,000</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-sm button-amount"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>10,000</button>
```

Comment: This seems to be a better idea! Thanks!